# Any way to make multiple files stop hiding their extension?

Tags: terminal, finder, uti

How can I make multiple files show their extension at once? Any finder setting and/or terminal command would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your goal is, but you make Finder show all extensions by default by selecting *Show all filename extensions* in *Finder -> Preferences -> Advanced*.